# Importing attributes and attribute sets to fresh install using MySQL data from old install

Tags: magento-1.9, import, attribute-set

The old site is no longer active. I have all the data, but I am not a good enough programmer to write scripts to import it. I've been trying to copy over the eav* tables and was able to import all the attributes on eav_attribute, but they do not display on the admin despite being there in the database. Then tried to copy over the eav_attribute_group and I am hitting foreign key constraints.

I am moderately proficient at SQL, not enough at programming to write my own import script. After searching this site, I have found a few people who were able to import using a script but they had the old site still active.

Does anybody know a way I could import the custom attributes and attribute sets from the old database SQL file into a fresh install using SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Easy my friend.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/
http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Import_Attributes_%26_Attribute_Sets

This module does what you need. All the documents are there. There is also a few paid ones, but in my opinion this works just as well.